# Why to set errno to zero at the time of initialization of the program and can't test it before error occurred?

Tags: c, error-handling, exit-status

I am reading the material available on `errno` variable of `<errno.h>` header file.

I read :

" A value of 0 indicates that there is no error in the program." and "As a good practice, developer should set `errno` to 0 at the time of initialization of the program"

By convention we check the `errno` variable only when there is an error occurred (like some of the function returned with -1).

Question 1 : Then what is the use of setting `errno` to 0 before starting the program.

More, I read that it is better to store the error number to the local variable and then to check it , i.e.

```
 if (somecall() == -1) {
      printf("somecall() failed\n");
      if (errno == ...) { ... }
      }
```

In above code it is possible that `printf()` function call can overwrite the value of `errno` , if some error occurs with `printf()`.

Question 2 : Does the above statement applies to `perror()` and `strerror()` , because they are also system calls , and there is possibility that the error occurred with them too.

In Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment by Richard Stevens , I read that we should examine the value of `errno` , only when the return value from a function indicates that an error occurred. I do not understand why ?

Answer (score 11):

> By convention we check the `errno` variable only when there is an error occurred (like some of the function returned with -1).
>
> Question 1 : Then what is the use of setting `errno` to 0 before starting the program.

Indeed we should only check `errno` in the case where an error occurred. This is because if no error occurred, then it is still possible that `errno` will contain a non-zero value (e.g. if an error occurred during the execution of a library call but the error was recovered).

As such, setting `errno` to 0 before "starting the program" is not necessary, and I wouldn't follow that advice.

> More, I read that it is better to store the error number to the local variable and then to check it

Yes! Your observation about `printf()` being able to clobber `errno` is correct. If its value needs to be preserved, it should be copied to a local variable as soon as possible after the error occurs.

> Question 2 : Does the above statement applies to perror() and strerror() , because they are also system calls , and there is possibility that the error occurred with them too.

`perror()` probably doesn't call anything that modifies `errno`, but if it does then it must be careful to copy the value of `errno` before that happens. I'm sure you can assume that `perror()` works correctly on your system!

`strerror()` doesn't need to worry about that because it takes the error number as a parameter, so even if where to clobber `errno` the previous value has already been saved.

> In Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment by Richard Stevens , I read that we should examine the value of `errno`, only when the return value from a function indicates that an error occurred. I do not understand why ?

Because system calls and library calls that set `errno` on failure are not required to set it on success, so it retains whatever value it had before.

Comment: `perror()` is not a system call but unless something has explicitly requested buffering on stderr,  it calls the `write()` system call that will set errno upon failure to write on fd 2. That shouldn't affect what message it tried to display as that would happen after the message has been prepared.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1, *why should we set `errno` to 0 at the beginning of the program* is that at some time some idiot may modify the program and use the `errno` value without checking that the previous system call failed (`errno` is only set upon failure, it's not reset to 0 on success).

`perror()` and `strerror()` are *not* system calls, they're library functions. They will take care to preserve the original value of `errno` at the time they're called. (Actually `strerror()` may be a macro (`#define`) so it should only be called when you know `errno` has a valid value.)